# JSF почему так работает а так нет?

Tags: jsf, link

Вот так я могу считать параметр (#{param.genre_id}) после перехода по ссылке:

```
<h:column>
      <h:link value="#{g.name}" outcome="books?genre_id=#{g.id}" styleClass="left_table_link"/>
</h:column>
```

А вот так нет:

```
<h:column>                
       <h:link value="#{g.name}">
             <ui:param name="genre_id" value="#{g.id}"/>
       </h:link>
</h:column>
```

Тоесть нужно остаться на тойже странице только передать в неё параметр.
Будо признателен за пояснение (Сейчас только изучаю JSF) интересно почему так.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо разобрался - использовал тег param jsf/facelets вместо jsf/core.